# Gmail and Calendar API for web app Platform

Tags: google-calendar-api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm currently developing an application offers a virtual session service using Google Meet. Here is my situation.

1. When a user sign up on my platform, I want to add the user in the Workspace Directory, create a domain specific email address for them and map it to their personal Gmail account so that anytime I schedule a session from my web app. In the meeting details, the domain specific email address I created for the user should appear in the attendee details but the user should still be able to attend the meeting with their personal Gmail account since I've mapped it with the domain specific email address.

Example:

1. User A signs up on my platform at health.com with usera@gmail.com
2. I want to create a user called usera@health.com
3. Then map usera@health.com to usera@gmail.com
4. So that when I create a Google Meet session, the details will be forwarded to usera@gmail.com
5. And usera@gmail.com should be able to attend the Google meet session.

I've found some resources like Recipient address maps at https://support.google.com/a/answer/4524505?hl=en I saw an options for bulk upload

I also found something similar that has to do with the usera@gmail.com going to their settings and enable some IMAP and POP mapping, I don't really know how it works.

Basically, what I want is a way to achieve the situation I explained above.

Is there a way? What do I need to know that I don't know.

Comment: wow that sounds like fun I think you're going to have an issue with your mapping plans.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaIm To Do you have ideas or simple way to at least do something like this or an alternative?